# How to solve this infinte series related to bessel integral?

Tags: special-functions

$$\int_0^z t^{\rho} J_{\mu}(at) J_{\nu}(bt) dt = \frac{(\frac 1 2 a z)^{\mu} (\frac 1 2 bz)^{\nu} z^{\rho + 1}}{\Gamma(\mu + 1)\Gamma(\nu + 1)} \times \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k (\frac 1 2 a z)^{2k} {}_2 F_1(-k, -\mu - k; \nu + 1; b^2/a^2)}{k!(\mu + \nu + \rho + 2k + 1)(\mu + 1)_k}, \Re(\mu + \nu + \rho) > -1$$

I would like to solve infinite series, in simplified form.

Comment: Do you have this in a better format by chance?

Comment: How did you arrive at this series, and what makes you assume a simplified form exists?

Comment: Very often finite integrals of special functions do not come out to anything nice. This isn't going to reduce to anything more simple than what you have, I'm afraid.

Comment: I don't know that I've ever seen a nice form of a partial integral (meaning not from $0$ to $\infty$, or of that flavor) of Bessel functions, and I don't expect this one to be any different.

Comment: I think wolfram alpha can solve this. I plugged in the integral and got a single hypergeometric function, not a series of them.

Comment: Scratch that. I forgot the scale factors $a$ and $b$ when I entered the integral into wolfram alpha. After adding them, WRA is no longer able to do the integral. Oops.